# MongoDB - $gte and $lte returning incorrect results - strange behaviour

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am absolutely stumped and do not know why this is happening. In MongoDB I have a simple collection as follows:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59bf7291d58e7c23182465f0"),
        "weekly_rent" : "299",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59bf8264d58e7c23182465f1"),
        "weekly_rent" : "199",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59bf9fe4d58e7c23182465f2"),
        "weekly_rent" : "899",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59c4e3316d55c10430d4ab16"),
        "weekly_rent" : "150",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59c4e3726d55c10430d4ab17"),
        "weekly_rent" : "120",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59c4e3aa6d55c10430d4ab18"),
        "weekly_rent" : "190",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59c4e3e76d55c10430d4ab19"),
        "weekly_rent" : "230",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59c4e42f6d55c10430d4ab1a"),
        "weekly_rent" : "100",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59c4e4616d55c10430d4ab1b"),
        "weekly_rent" : "400",
        "__v" : 0
}
```

When I perform a search using:

```
db.listings.find({weekly_rent: { $gte: "100", $lte: "300" }}).pretty()
```

I get the intended results with objects containing the weekly_rents: 100, 230, 190, 120, 150, 199, 299

But when I perform a search using:

```
db.listings.find({weekly_rent: { $gte: "99", $lte: "300" }}).pretty()
```

I get absolutely no results returned to me. Why am I getting nothing when the "greater than or equal" value has changed to 99, because all of these values are greater than 99.

Does this have something to do with the lowest weekly_rent object having a value of 100?

What is going on here and why does my query not work? I am stumped and cannot find any information on this. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fields and search parameters are strings, so you're getting lexicographical comparison. Just as `"zz" > "daa"`, so `"99" > "300"`. If you want to use numeric operations, you should probably store these values as numbers.

Comment: Oh wow you are right, what was I thinking.. Thanks so much for your answer it has helped me a lot!